# Missleading display of values in pandas column when each cell is a list

Tags: python, pandas

In jupiter notebook

This column made up of two different lists, are displayed the same way.

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    "user": ["a", "b"], 
    "values": [['1', '2, 1', '2', '3'], ['1, 2', '1, 2, 3']]
              })
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Q:** how to display these lists so that they look different.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but unfortunately you cannot avoid all ambiguities. Did you have a specific question?

Comment: Another example: `pd.Series([('a', 'b'), frozenset(['a', 'b'])])`

Comment: Even though you can (and sometimes have to) store lists/sequences in cells, they are generally a code smell. If you want to utilize the possibilities of pandas to their full potential, you should aim at wrangling your data in a way that each cell contains only a single, atomic value. In this case, you might want to `explode` the `values` column.

Comment: @mozway sorry, shold have framed it as a question, was more to point out for other users to be careful. 

but the question is "how to avoid this display"

Comment: @fsimonjetz This is why I have a list in the df: 

I was expecting a df to have single intger-like string eg"1" or "2" for each cell. 
while instead I got some double values "1, 3" or "2, 5". 
I just wanted to visualize which columns had this issue, so i made a dict
dict_doubles[col] = {'values': df[df[col].astype(str).str.contains(",")].unique()} , just to check what values where double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the exact question, but yes there is ambiguity.

You also have ambiguity with other data types. For example tuples and frozensets look alike:

```
pd.Series([('a', 'b'), frozenset(['a', 'b'])])

0    (a, b)
1    (a, b)
dtype: object
```

One thing you could do would be to use the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of your objects, which doesn't fully avoid ambiguity but makes things a bit more explicit for strings and tuples/frozensets:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a, b', 'b, c, d', 'c'], 
    'B': [1, 2, 3]
})

df.applymap(repr)

           A  B
0     'a, b'  1
1  'b, c, d'  2
2        'c'  3

pd.Series([('a', 'b'), frozenset(['a', 'b'])]).apply(repr)

0               ('a', 'b')
1    frozenset({'a', 'b'})
dtype: object
```

Note that using lists as items is usually not a good practice in pandas (this doesn't allow vectorial functions).

Comment: Thanks, there seems to be a solution for everything in python.